# PHP Registration script - Validation always fails

Tags: php, validation

I've been writing a registration script for a website which checks the input of each  field in order (9 in total) and once all they've all been checked it completes the code in the middle between `"{//9"` and `"}// close9"`.

However if any of the checks fail, the script is supposed to assign a value of "failed" to the variable `$GLOBALS['fail']`, which in turn should return the echo "registration failed" at the bottom of the page.

But even when the `$GLOBALS['fail']` variable is assigned a value of `passed` it is still echoing "registration failed" and despite everything I have tried it will not stop.

I have even entered `echo $GLOBALS['fail'];` to check the value it is assigned **right before** the `if($GLOBALS['fail'] = "failed")` function is called.

Below is the code:

```
<?php 
//first visit
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{//first visit

if(isset($_POST['firstname'])&&(!empty($_POST['firstname'])))
{//1
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
echo $firstname . "<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['surname'])&&(!empty($_POST['surname'])))
{//2
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
echo $surname. "<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['username'])&&(!empty($_POST['username'])))
{//3
$username = $_POST['username'];
echo $username. "<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['password1'])&&(!empty($_POST['password1'])))
{//4
$pass1 = $_POST['password1'];
echo $pass1. "<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['password2'])&&(!empty($_POST['password2'])))
{//5
$pass2 = $_POST['password2'];
echo $pass2. "<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['day'])&&(!empty($_POST['day'])))
{//6
$day = $_POST['day'];
echo $day. "<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['month'])&&(!empty($_POST['month'])))
{//7
$month = $_POST['month'];
echo $month. "<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['year'])&&(!empty($_POST['year'])))
{//8
$year = $_POST['year'];
echo $year. "<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['email'])&&(!empty($_POST['email'])))
{//9
$email = $_POST['email'];
echo $email. "<br/>" ."well done";
$GLOBALS['fail'] = "passed";
echo $GLOBALS['fail'];

} //close9

else {$GLOBALS['fail']="failed"; echo "Please fill in <b>All</b> fields " ;}

} //close8

else {$GLOBALS['fail']="failed"; echo "Please fill in <b>All</b> fields " ;}

} //close7

else {$GLOBALS['fail']="failed"; echo "Please fill in <b>All</b> fields " ;}

} //close6

else {$GLOBALS['fail']="failed"; echo "Please fill in <b>All</b> fields " ;}

} //close5

else {$GLOBALS['fail']="failed"; echo "Please fill in <b>All</b> fields " ;}

} //close4

else {$GLOBALS['fail']="failed"; echo "Please fill in <b>All</b> fields " ;}

} //close3

else {$GLOBALS['fail']="failed"; echo "Please fill in <b>All</b> fields " ;}

} //close2

else {$GLOBALS['fail']="failed"; echo "Please fill in <b>All</b> fields " ;}

} //close1

else {$GLOBALS['fail']="failed"; echo "Please fill in <b>All</b> fields " ;}

} //firstvisit

else echo "stupidity";

echo $GLOBALS['fail'];

if(isset($GLOBALS['fail'])){
if($GLOBALS['fail']="failed"){
echo "registration failed";
}
else echo $GLOBALS['fail'];
}
else echo "no fail set";
?>
```

The output on the screen when I press register and the whole form is complete is **well donepassedpassedregistration failed**

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: When I first visit the page it always echoes "Stupidity" and "No fail set" but **if($GLOBALS['fail']="failed")** always returns "registration failed" except on the first visit to the page even when **$GLOBALS['fail']** is assigned a value of **"passed"**.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if($GLOBALS['fail'] === "failed"){}
```

Or:

```
if($GLOBALS['fail'] == "failed"){}
```

You can't compare with one "=", you need to use 2 to compare the value and 3 if you want to compare type as well.

Comment: I wish I'd asked sooner. I've been trying for a combined total of over 4 hours to try and sort that problem out and you've given me an answer in less than five minutes. I feel quite stupid now :/

The funny thing is, I'd said to my girlfriend that I had a feeling it was something simple!!

Thank you soooo much!!